# Python – Have a variable be both an int and a str

Tags: python, string, int, primes

Here is my code:

```
def retest2():
    print "Type in another chapter title! Or type \"Next\" to move on."
    primenumbers2()
def primenumbers1():
    print "--------------------------------------------------\nChapters in books are usually given the cardinal numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and so on.\nBut I have decided to give my chapters prime numbers 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 and so on because I like prime numbers.\n\nType in the chapter title of my book (a prime number) and I will tell you what cardinal number the chapter is."
def primenumbers2():
    prime = (str(input("\n")))
    chapter = (2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233)

    if "Next" in prime or "next" in prime:
        print "--------------------------------------------------\nOnto the next thing."
    elif int(prime) in chapter:
        print "Chapter ",chapter.index(int(prime)) + 1
        retest2()
    elif prime.isalpha:
        print "That is not one of my chapter numbers because {0} is not a prime number. Try again.".format(prime)
        primenumbers2()

primenumbers1()
primenumbers2()
```

So what I'm trying to do is having the user input a prime number and the output is the cardinal number correlating to that prime number. However, I want the user to have the option of going onto the next function by typing in `"Next"` or `"next"`. Therefore, my variable input `prime` needs to accomodate for both string and integer input. So I set it as `(str(input("\n")))` and then I converted it to `int(prime)` when I needed to.

Everything works well except when the string input is anything but `"Next"` or `"next"`. For example, if I input "okay", I get the error message:

```
File "prime.py", line x, in primenumbers2
    prime = (str(input("\n")))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'okay' is not defined
```

But if I input "4", which is NOT a prime number, the program works and I get:

```
That is not one of my chapter numbers because 4 is not a prime number. Try again.
```

And the program loops back to `primenumbers2()` to restart that function.

Please help me make this work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `raw_input` for python2, `input` in python2 is basically `eval(raw_input())` and as you have no variable `okay` defined you get the error.

```
In [10]: prime = (str(input("\n")))

foo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-15ff4b8b32ce> in <module>()
----> 1 prime = (str(input("\n")))

<string> in <module>()

NameError: name 'foo' is not defined    
In [11]: foo = 1 
In [12]: prime = (str(input("\n")))
foo
In [13]: prime = (raw_input("\n"))
next
In [14]: print prime
next
```

You should rarely if ever use `input`.

You should also use a while loop, something like the following:

```
 def primenumbers2():
    chapter = (
        2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107,
        109,
        113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233)
    while True:
        prime = input("Type in another chapter title! Or type \"Next\" to move on.")
        if "next"  == prime.lower():
            print("--------------------------------------------------\nOnto the next thing.")
            break
        try:
            p = int(prime)
            if p in chapter:
                print("Chapter {}".format(chapter.index(p) + 1))
            else:
                 print("That is not one of my chapter numbers because {0}"
                  " is not a prime number. Try again.".format(prime))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input")
```

Not totally sure what you want to do but using a while, checking if the user input is  equal to `next` and if not trying to cast to int using a try/except is a better idea.

Making chapters a dict would also be a better idea, accessing the chapter number by key:

```
def primenumbers2():
    chaps = (
        2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107,
        109,
        113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233)

    chapter = dict(zip(chaps, range(1, len(chaps) + 1)))
    while True:
        prime = input("Type in another chapter title! Or type \"Next\" to move on.")
        if "next" == prime.lower():
            print("--------------------------------------------------\nOnto the next thing.")
            break
        try:
            p = int(prime)
            if p in chapter:
                print("Chapter {}".format(chapter[p]))
            else:
                print("That is not one of my chapter numbers because {}"
                      " is not a prime number. Try again.".format(prime))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input")
```

`range(1, len(chaps) + 1))` will mean each `p` in chapter will have a value corresponding to its index in the tuple.

Comment: Thank you, I used a variation of this and it works. Instead of putting `else` outside of the `try` block, I put `elif p not in chapter` within the `try` block.

Comment: @theo1010, no prob, I pasted the wrong code, you need to break the while when the user enters next or call some other function if that is what you had planned. I was not totally sure what your full idea was.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is converting a value entered by the user to a string or an int. If you use `input`, which as Padraic says is equals to `eval(raw_input())`, you will eval the input as it was a python command: this will throw an error if you write any non existing name. To resolve this, use the `raw_input` function. It will return a `str` object, the input text.

Then, you want to find if this text is a number, or a string. One solution is using exceptions :

```
try:
    prime = int(prime)

    # Here the code assuming prime is a number, an `int`
except ValueError:
    # here the code assuming prime is a string, `str`, for example
    # 'Next', 'next' or 'okay'
```

Comment: If I type in a number that is not prime, I get an error message: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isalpha'`

Comment: @theo1010 Sorry, I paste your code without checking... If prime is a number, then the execution of the code will continue after `prime = int(prime)`, and prime will be an `int`. So, you must do the code assuming prime is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using isdigit to avoid the exception:

```
def primenumbers2():
prime = (str(input("\n")))
chapter = (2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233)

if "Next" in prime or "next" in prime:
    print "--------------------------------------------------\nOnto the next thing."
elif prime.isdigit() and int(prime) in chapter:
    print "Chapter ",chapter.index(int(prime)) + 1
    retest2()
else:
    print "That is not one of my chapter numbers because {0} is not a prime number. Try again.".format(prime)
    primenumbers2()
```